# Check if MIC is locked or used by other iOS application

Tags: ios, avfoundation, microphone, video-recording, voice-recording

I want to detect whether MIC is currently locked or used by any other iOS application. I didn't get any information to check if MIC is available for use or not ? I don't want to allow user to record video if MIC is already used by some other application , active call , facetime call.

Can anybody tell me the way to solve this issue ?

Thanks in advance.

**Update: Adding function to check if MIC is busy**

```
+(BOOL)isMicResourceBusy
{
    NSError *error = nil;

    NSMutableDictionary *recordSettings = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:10];
    NSNumber *formatObject;
    formatObject = [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC ];

    [recordSettings setObject:formatObject forKey: AVFormatIDKey];
    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey: AVSampleRateKey];
    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];
    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:12800] forKey:AVEncoderBitRateKey];
    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:16] forKey:AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey];
    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt: AVAudioQualityHigh] forKey: AVEncoderAudioQualityKey];

    NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[FileUtils getNewFilenameWithPrefix:@"testAudioRecording" ext:@"aac"]];

    AVAudioRecorder *audioRecorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc]initWithURL:soundFileURL settings:recordSettings error:&error];

    if ([audioRecorder prepareToRecord] && error == nil)
    {
        return NO;
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not think there is a way to check if the microphone is being used by another app.  There is a method [AVCaptureDevice lockForConfiguration] but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Sometimes we need to check if, i think so, eg: webrtc call does not release all the reference to audio, so the ***orange dot*** still alive in top of iphone

Answer (score 1):

You can try `[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] inputNumberOfChannels]` and check if the value is 0. Too bad, I can't find any documentation for this

Answer (score 1):

use `if AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().isOtherAudioPlaying == true{｝`

can solve this problem.

Comment: not solved, for my case, when the WebRTC call has not release all, so the ***orange dot*** still alive, next time user can talk anything.. @ErayAlparslan